# Parse the output of sql query in Google script to simple array

Tags: sql, parsing, google-apps-script

I used this code I found on stack overflow

```
function method3()
{
var spreadsheetID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var queryColumnLetterStart = 'A';
var queryColumnLetterEnd = 'B';
var queryColumnLetterSearch = 'B';
var query = 8;
    // SQL like query
    myQuery = "SELECT * WHERE " + queryColumnLetterSearch + " = '" + query + "'";

    // the query URL
    // don't provide last row in range selection
    var qvizURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetID + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=' + sheetName + '&range=' + queryColumnLetterStart + ":" + queryColumnLetterEnd + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(myQuery);
    Logger.log('qvizURL: '+qvizURL);

    // fetch the data
    var ret = UrlFetchApp.fetch(qvizURL, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
    Logger.log(ret);

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(ret.replace("/*O_o*/", "").replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", "").slice(0, -2));
    Logger.log('obj1:');
    Logger.log(obj1);

/* 2021-02-16 19:10CET - I added the code below that heads towards a solution - see output */
    var obj2 = obj1.table;
    Logger.log('obj2:');
    Logger.log(obj2);
    var obj3 = obj1.table.rows;
    Logger.log('obj3:');
    Logger.log(obj3);


}
```

Output after update:

```
19:12:17    Informatie  qvizURL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*********/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=Form Responses 1&range=A:B&tq=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20B%20%3D%20'8'
19:12:17    Informatie  ret: /*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"326840072","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Timestamp","type":"datetime","pattern":"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"},{"id":"B","label":"Klant ID","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)","f":"2/9/2021 22:22:12"},{"v":"8"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)","f":"2/9/2021 23:39:46"},{"v":"8"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":1}});
19:12:17    Informatie  obj1:
19:12:17    Informatie  {table={parsedNumHeaders=1.0, cols=[{id=A, pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss, label=Timestamp, type=datetime}, {type=string, id=B, label=Klant ID}], rows=[{c=[{v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12), f=2/9/2021 22:22:12}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}]}, version=0.6, sig=326840072, status=ok, reqId=0}
19:12:17    Informatie  obj2:
19:12:17    Informatie  {cols=[{label=Timestamp, pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss, type=datetime, id=A}, {label=Klant ID, id=B, type=string}], rows=[{c=[{f=2/9/2021 22:22:12, v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}], parsedNumHeaders=1.0}
19:12:17    Informatie  obj3:
19:12:17    Informatie  [{c=[{v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12), f=2/9/2021 22:22:12}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}]
```

The result I am looking for is a 2 dimensional array with just the timestamps and the customerID that I can process further in my script.

How can I parse that extensive output to that simple array?

This is how the output looks like. Seems pretty structured...

```
 version=0.6,
 table={
    rows=[
        {
            c=[
                {
                    f=2/9/2021 22:22:12,
                    v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)
                },
                {
                    v=8
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            c=[
                {
                    f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, 
                    v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)
                },
                {
                    v=8
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    parsedNumHeaders=1.0,
    cols=[
        {
            label=Timestamp,
            pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss, 
            id=A, 
            type=datetime
        },
        {
            type=string, 
            id=B, 
            label=customerIDID
        }
    ]
    },
 status=ok,
 reqId=0,
 sig=326840072
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Logger.log or console.log of the JSON before it's parsed

Comment: ```/*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"326840072","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Timestamp","type":"datetime","pattern":"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"},{"id":"B","label":"Klant ID","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)","f":"2/9/2021 22:22:12"},{"v":"8"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)","f":"2/9/2021 23:39:46"},{"v":"8"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":1}});```

Comment: I would expect an output that would look like [{Timestamp: "2/9/2021 22:22:12", CustomerID: "8"}, {Timestamp: "2/9/2021 23:39:46", CustomerID: "8"}]. I cant find documentation/tutorial how to process that 'complex' output with JSON.

Comment: Just added some new code and output that heads towards a solution. Still looking for last step(s) to get the data from the object..

Comment: Guess I need to use obj2 to retrieve my data, but have no clue how. Tried several ways like obj[0][0], obj[0]['Timestamp'], obj[0].Timestamp...

Comment: I don't see the structure in the result that you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't this do the same thing that you want: `function method3() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  const vs=rg.getValues();
}`

Comment: Then I would have to loop through all the records to find the record(s) I am looking for. If the range gets really large, the script will get very slow. Using the query would make it much faster.

Comment: The output of obj2 looks like something that I could get into an array that I could use. But I just cant get that working.

Comment: How do you specify what you're looking for

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Maybe this helps. The table actually consists of 3 columns: (A) timestamp, (B) customerID, (C) ordernumber. With the query I select all records for a specific customerID. Then in Google Script I want to loop through the results of the query to get the Timestamp, customerID and ordernumber for further processing.  I just can't get the results of the query into a Google Script array.

Comment: I added the output in a more structured view. Looks pretty structured to me. But no clue how to process it

Comment: I don't see the order number in the output.  It's only showing two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

```
function method3()
  {
    var spreadsheetID = 'xxxxxxx';
    var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
    var queryColumnLetterStart = 'A';
    var queryColumnLetterEnd = 'C';
    var query = 'select * where B = "8"';

    // don't provide last row in range selection
    var qvizURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetID + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=' + sheetName + '&range=' + queryColumnLetterStart + ":" + queryColumnLetterEnd + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(query);//(myQuery);
    Logger.log('qvizURL: ' + qvizURL);
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};

    // fetch the data
    Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
    var ret = UrlFetchApp.fetch(qvizURL, { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
    Logger.log('ret: ' + ret);

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(ret.replace("/*O_o*/", "").replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", "").slice(0, -2));
    Logger.log('obj1:');
    Logger.log(obj1);
    var data = obj1.table.rows;
    Logger.log('#rows: ' + data.length);

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      values.push({ts:obj.table.rows[i].c[0].f, cs:obj.table.rows[i].c[1].v, or:obj.table.rows[i].c[2].v})
      Logger.log(i+': ' + values[i][ts] + ' || ' + values[i][cs] + ' || ' + values[i][or] + ' || ');
    }
  }
```

(Only issue now is that it is working when triggered from a formSubmit. Not if I trigger it manually from AppScript. See [Receiving a 401 'truncated server' response in Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268685/receiving-a-401-truncated-server-response-in-google-apps-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the customer order number in the output at all.  But if you can supply this valid json then I think it with produce and array of objects with ts and id

```
function loadDataInArray(json) {
  const obj=JSON.parse(json);
  const data:obj.table.rows;
  let values:[];
  for(var i:0;i<data.length;i++) {
     values.push({ts:obj.table.rows[i].c[0].f,id:obj.table.rows[i].c[1].v})
  }
 }
```

But what you have above is not valid json.

and this is the way I'd get data.

```
function method3() {   
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);   
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');   
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);   
  const vs=rg.getValues(); 
  return vs;//a 2 d array
}
```

And if you were doing this using an onFormSubmit trigger you could get all of your data from the triggers event object via either values or namedValues

Comment: The push syntax helped me understand the structure of the son string. Made some manual tests and got that working. Thanks so far!

Comment: Now challenge remains why my code generates invalid json, or better: how to generate valid json. Not sure if it relates to UrlFetch. Wonder if I could somehow apply a query on the data if I would retrieve the data in the more straightforward way you wrote in method3 function.

Comment: The question I wonder about is why do you want to get data that way

Comment: Because I want to query it. And I only found the possibility to query using that urlfetch...

Comment: Only other way I can come up with is looping through all records. But that would increase runtime ...

Comment: Are accessing google sheets from another language?

Comment: But if you would have an easier way to query that data ...

Comment: The last part of my answer returns vs which is a 2 d array of the values in  'A2:B'