# Receiving a 401 'truncated server' response in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code.

```
  function method3()
  {
    var spreadsheetID = '1BGi80ZBoChrMXGOyCbu2pn0ptIL6uve2ib62gV-db_o';
    var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
    var queryColumnLetterStart = 'A';
    var queryColumnLetterEnd = 'C';
    var query = 'select * where B = "8"';

    // don't provide last row in range selection
    var qvizURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetID + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=' + sheetName + '&range=' + queryColumnLetterStart + ":" + queryColumnLetterEnd + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(query);//(myQuery);
    Logger.log('qvizURL: ' + qvizURL);
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};

    // fetch the data
    Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
    var ret = UrlFetchApp.fetch(qvizURL, { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
    Logger.log('ret: ' + ret);

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(ret.replace("/*O_o*/", "").replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", "").slice(0, -2));
    Logger.log('obj1:');
    Logger.log(obj1);
    var data = obj1.table.rows;
    Logger.log('#rows: ' + data.length);

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      values.push({ts:obj.table.rows[i].c[0].f, cs:obj.table.rows[i].c[1].v, or:obj.table.rows[i].c[2].v})
      Logger.log(i+': ' + values[i][ts] + ' || ' + values[i][cs] + ' || ' + values[i][or] + ' || ');
    }
  }
```

Logger:

```
18 feb. 2021 22:33:44   Informatie  qvizURL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGi80ZBoChrMXGOyCbu2pn0ptIL6uve2ib62gV-db_o/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=Form Responses 1&range=A:C&tq=select%20*%20where%20B%20%3D%20%228%22
18 feb. 2021 22:33:44   Informatie  ya29.A0AfH6SMBGpL2mxU7DO5p8RQfCXKP1w13wmU6aBTVZSCjfO-uj_xzkYQziMhnXATEdGREibJk9cATEGioTfQG4aGsNq7Tm05_oD0z1HKu1v4ozBF_B2XegyQ-NuXBJFmJWTX5WEpTOm0RDTlfY6uw8lK3R5HTV
18 feb. 2021 22:33:44   Fout    Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
 (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at method3(QueryTable:16:27)
```

Tried adding' muteHttpExceptions:true'. But this just showed the HTML from the url I fetched. Was truncated and didn't show any clues.

Do I somewhere need to give authorization for this UrlFetch?

**** update ***

Everything was created with one and the same account.

This was the initial version of the manifest (appscript.json):

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"}
```

Then I added oauthScopes
as I read on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#viewing_scopes

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
}
```

This produced: "Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request".

So I added

```
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
```

That produced the initial error message: Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: ...

So guess I some more finetuning of the oauthScopes is required ... Looked through https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-scopes#editor_scopes, but not sure what to do...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `It is almost identical to code I run in another Google Script, which works fine. But this one generates an error.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the difference between `It is almost identical to code I run in another Google Script, which works fine.` and `But this one generates an error.`?

Comment: If you get a 401, then of course you aren't authorized and you need to authorize the request. Whoever this script executes as does not have permission to access that file, whether that's due to a Drive file sharing issue or due to lack of OAuth scope grant in the script manifest.

Comment: Hi Tanike. Ignore that. (I removed comment). If I trigger the function via a formSubmit, the code works fine. When I run it manually from AppScript I get the error.

Comment: @tehhowch. I do get that OAuth. I trigger it from the same account that I built the code with. Is there somewhere a setting I need to change?

Comment: So I followed this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes. Then I got this message: "Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request". So I added " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request" to the script manifest as well, but then got the original error message back...

Comment: Who created the form submit trigger? Who owns the spreadsheet that you're trying to access? Does the script have the OAuth scope necessary to _read a spreadsheet_? These are all details you need to provide.

Comment: Everything was created with one and the same account.

Comment: See changes I made to the manifest and its results. See additional info in my issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Your credentials are not valid, use Sheets Advanced Service instead

The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

On the other side server that receives valid credentials that are not adequate to gain access ought to respond with the 403 (Forbidden) status code.

As I can see in your code you want to iterate over your sheets data by getting the Spreadsheet range in a JSON format. I'd recommend you to use Sheets Advanced Service in Google Apps script and make the following changes:

Click on **Services +** and add Sheets API V4.

[image]

**Get values through Sheets API in Google Apps Script and then filter**

```
function SheetsAdvancedService()
{
  var spreadsheetID = 'ID';
  var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
  var queryColumnLetterStart = 'A';
  var queryColumnLetterEnd = 'C';

  var sheetRangeResponse = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetID, `${sheetName}!${queryColumnLetterStart}:${queryColumnLetterEnd}`);
  if (sheetRangeResponse.values) {
    var filteredData = sheetRangeResponse.values.filter(row => row[1] == 8) // select * where B = "8"
    Logger.log(filteredData);
    // Handle data ...
    // Or use forEach instead of filter for efficiency
  } else {
    Logger.log("No values");
  }
}
```

### Or use SheetsApp and then filter

```
function SheetsThroughGoogleAppsScript()
{
  var spreadsheetID = 'ID';
  var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheets.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (range) {
    var filteredData = range.filter(row => row[1] == 8) // select * where B = "8"
    Logger.log(filteredData);
    // Handle data and filter columns ...
    // Or use forEach instead of filter for efficiency
  } else {
    Logger.log("No values");
  }
}
```

### References

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)

Comment: Thanks Jose. I took a brief look at it. Might be a good way to go. Will take another look at it later on, due to other priorities.